# Missing column labels after filling missing values in scikit-learn

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, imputation

I was recently tried to fill missing data in a dataset after which the column labels in the dataset disappeared.
The dataset is was using looks like:

|  | Make | Colour | Odometer (KM) | Doors |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Honda | White | 35431.0 | 4.0 |
| 1 | BMW | Blue | 192714.0 | 5.0 |
| 2 | Honda | White | 84714.0 | 4.0 |
| 3 | Toyota | White | 154365.0 | 4.0 |
| 4 | Nissan | Blue | 181577.0 | 3.0 |

The method I used is

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

cat_imputer=SimpleImputer(strategy='constant',fill_value='missing')
door_imputer=SimpleImputer(strategy='constant',fill_value=4)
num_imputer=SimpleImputer(strategy="mean")

cat_features=["Make","Colour"]
door_features=["Doors"]
num_features=["Odometer (KM)"]

imputer = ColumnTransformer([
    ("cat_imputer",cat_imputer,cat_features),
    ("door_imputer",door_imputer,door_features),
    ("num_imputer",num_imputer,num_features)
])

filled_x=imputer.fit_transform(X)
new_frame=pd.DataFrame(filled_x)
```

After this, if we view the **new_frame** it is

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Honda | White | 4.0 | 35431.04.0 |
| 1 | BMW | Blue | 5.0 | 192714.0 |
| 2 | Honda | White | 4.0 | 84714.0 |
| 3 | Toyota | White | 4.0 | 154365.0 |
| 4 | Nissan | Blue | 3.0 | 181577.0 |

So what happened here?

**Why are the Doors and Odometer (KM) columns flipped?**
**Where did the column labels go?**
**How can I bring them back?**

Answer (score 1):

because it generates a whole new `filled_x` array, which the type is `numpy.ndarray`, either you assign them back to the original `dataframe` or to a new `dataframe` equipt with old `dataframe`'s columns and index.

```
df
###
     Make Colour  Odometer (KM)  Doors
0   Honda  White        35431.0    4.0
1     BMW   Blue       192714.0    5.0
2   Honda    NaN        84714.0    4.0
3  Toyota  White       154365.0    4.0
4  Nissan   Blue       181577.0    NaN
```

**I remodify your `df` with some `NaN`, so we can check if the imputer works or not.**

#### Imputation

> Why are the Doors and Odometer (KM) columns flipped?

Your `imputer`'s orders differ from your original `dataframe`'s column order.

```
cat_imputer=SimpleImputer(strategy='constant',fill_value='missing')
door_imputer=SimpleImputer(strategy='constant',fill_value=4)
num_imputer=SimpleImputer(strategy="mean")

cat_features=["Make","Colour"]
door_features=["Doors"]
num_features=["Odometer (KM)"]

imputer = ColumnTransformer([
    ("cat_imputer",cat_imputer,cat_features),
    ("num_imputer",num_imputer,num_features),     ◀━┓
    ("door_imputer",door_imputer,door_features)   ◀━┛
])

filled_x=imputer.fit_transform(df)
```

```
filled_x
###
[['Honda' 'White' 35431.0 4.0]
 ['BMW' 'Blue' 192714.0 5.0]
 ['Honda' 'missing' 84714.0 4.0]
 ['Toyota' 'White' 154365.0 4.0]
 ['Nissan' 'Blue' 181577.0 4.0]]
```

During the processing, `sklearn` are dealing with `array`/`ndarray`

```
type(filled_x)
###
numpy.ndarray
```

you use `pd.DataFrame(filled_x)` that made the `ndarray`-format result from `imputer.fit_transform()` putting into a brand new `dataframe` without specifying columns and index information.

You may assign them like:

```
new_frame = pd.DataFrame(filled_x, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
new_frame
###
```

[image]

And this is a way(though it's not recommended) to assign the result to overwrite the old `df`

```
df.loc[:,:] = filled_x
```

Practically speaking, we might reserve `df` so you can try different imputation methods.